# Change color of selected link in angular 4

Tags: angular, html, css

I made a header using bootstrap 4 but  I want that when I click on any link, link change its color and remains selected.

```
<nav>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" id="nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/experience">Experience</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/skills">Skills</a>
          </li>
        <ul>
     <div>
<nav>
```

I don't know what to do next, I don't want to use jquery.

Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at the [RouterLinkActive directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive), that should do what you want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `routerLinkActive`

> ```
> .html file
> ```

```
<nav>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">
        <ul class="navbar-nav" id="nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="" routerLinkActive="class-name" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/experience" routerLinkActive="class-name" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}">Experience</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/skills" routerLinkActive="class-name" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}">Skills</a>
          </li>
        <ul>
     <div>
<nav>
```

> .css/.scss file

```
.class-name{
    color:red;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use **RouterLinkActive**

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/experience" 
   routerLinkActive="YourClass" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}">
    Experience
</a>
```

`routerLinkActive` - Assign your class.
`routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}"` - add the class when match the exact link